# Display block not working in html / css. What are other alternatives?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to format this grid list in a way, so it would be displayed vertically.

[image: image with display block]

Yet, I cannot override the CSS or set its parent to `display: block;`. I also tried with `!important`, but to no use. Here is an example of how it should look like:

[image: How I want it]

Edit: This is what is pre-written in Elements window.

[image: Element window]

grid.component.html:

```
    <mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="50px">
  <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let movie of movies.results; index as i" >
    <img src="{{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + movies.results[i].poster_path}}">
    <a class="button" href="https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/{{movies.results[i].id}}" >Details</a>
    <p>{{ movies.results[i].original_title }}</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

grid.component.css:

```
.mat-grid-list{
  background-color: red;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

mat-grid-tile{
  display: block !important;
}

.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code, I will make chances to work in the same way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox, as shown below. `mat-grid-list` could be a flex container with the default flex direction of 'row' and each `mat-grid-tile` would be a flex container with the flex direction of 'column.' All you need to know about flexbox is here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
mat-grid-list {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

mat-grid-tile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="4" gutterSize="50px">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let movie of movies.results; index as i">
    <img src="{{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + movies.results[i].poster_path}}">
    <a class="button" href="https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/{{movies.results[i].id}}">Details</a>
    <p>{{ movies.results[i].original_title }}</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let movie of movies.results; index as i">
    <img src="{{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + movies.results[i].poster_path}}">
    <a class="button" href="https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/{{movies.results[i].id}}">Details</a>
    <p>{{ movies.results[i].original_title }}</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let movie of movies.results; index as i">
    <img src="{{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + movies.results[i].poster_path}}">
    <a class="button" href="https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/{{movies.results[i].id}}">Details</a>
    <p>{{ movies.results[i].original_title }}</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but it's not working. I updated information about this question.

Comment: @norcek10 does adding `flex-direction: column;` to the `mat-figure` class not give  you want you want?

Comment: Try flex-box. It's easy. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @dikuw Unfortunatelly no.